# React Redux - passing props with actions

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I have a simple component that I'd like to toggle depending on its props. Code looks as follows:

**actions.js**

```
const toggleTodo = (id) => {
  return {
    type: 'TODOITEM__TOGGLE_TODO',
    id
  }
};

export {
  toggleTodo
}
```

**component.js**

```
import React from 'react';

const TodoItem = (props) => {
  const completed = props.isDone === true ? 'done' : '';

  return (
    <li className={completed} id={props.id} onClick={props.toggle}>{props.text}</li>
  );
}

export default TodoItem;
```

**container.js**

```
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import component from './component';
import * as actions from './actions';

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return state;
};

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
  return {
    toggle: (id) => { dispatch(actions.toggleTodo(id)); }
  }
};

const TodoItem = connect(
  mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps
)(component);

export default TodoItem;
```

**reducers.js**

```
const todoItemReducer = (state = [], action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'TODOITEM__TOGGLE_TODO':
      console.log(action.id);
      return state;
  }

  return state;
};

export default todoItemReducer;
```

**index.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { createStore } from 'redux';

import TodoItem from './components/TodoItem/container';

import reducers from './reducers';

const store = createStore(reducers, window.devToolsExtension && window.devToolsExtension());

render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <TodoItem key="1" isDone={false} text="Test" id="1" />
  </Provider>,
  app
);
```

**reducers.js**

```
import { combineReducers } from 'redux';

// Reducers
import todoItemReducer from './components/TodoItem/reducers';

const reducers = combineReducers({
  todoItemReducer
});

export default reducers;
```

When I run this and click on the said component, console returns an `event` object. What can I do to pass something there?

Please note that I used `onClick={() => { props.toggle(props.id) }}` before, but I don't think that this is a proper way.

Comment: I am doing this - and `action.id` (in your example, `action.payload`) is an `event` (click) object.

Comment: yes, understand, my comment was already covered in your code... onClick, you need to pass the `id` right? the method for toggle is missing i think..

Comment: Where this method should be, and how should it look?

Comment: Your reducer doesn't do anything. Your id should be a number or a string, not an event object. In `mapStateToProps` you select the entire state rather than just a particular todo item.

Comment: @DDS, I know it should be a number or string, but how can I pass it? My reducer doesn't do anything since I can't get the `id` to work.

Comment: Also, the root reducer seems to be entirely missing but I'm (perhaps incorrectly) assuming you just didn't include that code.

Comment: @DDS, I've edited the question and put the rest of the code there.

Comment: You get the id from props. Currently your code seems to not contain any concrete data at all and this means there is no id and no other data such as text or completed field either.  It's up to the reducer to shape the state. With the reducer not doing anything, you don't have any state.

Comment: I understand. But I have an `id` prop passed (as a dummy content, true, but still) in both `component.js` and in `index.js`.

Answer (score 3):

`mapStateToProps` needs to select a single todo based on props (an id prop to be exact). You also have to create a reducer for todo items (plural!). This reducer calls the one for a single item reducer. You should look at the standard [Redux todo example](http://redux.js.org/docs/basics/ExampleTodoList.html) which does everything you need.

Note in the example there are two reducers, one for the list of reducers and one for a single reducer.

Answer (score 2):

Reducers.js return isDone

```
  const todoItemReducer = (state = [], action) => {
      switch (action.type) {
        case 'TODOITEM__TOGGLE_TODO':
          console.log(action.id);
          return {
             isDone: !state.isDone
         };
      }

      return state;
    };

    export default todoItemReducer;
```

Container.js

```
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import component from './component';
import * as actions from './actions';

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return {
isDone: state.isDone
};
};

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
  return {
    toggle: (id) => { dispatch(actions.toggleTodo(id)); }
  }
};

const TodoItem = connect(
  mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps
)(component);

export default TodoItem;
```

Component.js

```
import React from 'react';

const TodoItem = (props) => {
  const completed = props.isDone === true ? 'done' : '';

  return (
    <li className={completed} id={props.id} onClick={props.toggle.bind(this,props.id}>{props.text}</li>
  );
}

export default TodoItem;
```

Comment: Thanks, but I need to pass an `id`, as I've written in my question.

Comment: added component.js use bind

Comment: just used bind props.toggle.bind(this,this.props.id) . Javascript bind returns a new function and this function when invoked will preserve the context and the previous arguments.

Comment: Please be careful with this code. The initial state is an array and then `isDone` is set on that array. It works but it's a terrible idea. Also it manages only a single todo and only the `isDone` prop. I suggest strongly you take a look at the canonical redux example.

Comment: state should be an Object

Comment: In the code posted above the initial state is clearly an array. I am assuming the idea of this todo app will be to have more than a single todo so having an array somewhere might not be such a bad idea. It should be in a separate reducer however. This reducer is completely missing. Also, the todo has no text, title, id (!) or anything else. To see how to build these, please take a look at the official example.

Comment: Please note that this is a very reduced example, and it actually features only one item. My point here was to learn how to create actions, reducers etc.